# Not Able to Trigger the Exception NO_DATA_FOUND in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am not able to trigger the exceptions NO_DATA_FOUND from functions in PostgreSql 8.2 even if the returned rows or result sets is zero.

Here is my code;

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_ex() RETURNS trigger AS  

$func_ex$
    DECLARE               
        var_name  name;                 
    BEGIN
           Select empname INTO var_name from emp_table1 WHERE empid = 161232;  

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'No data found';
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
  return new
$func_ex$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
-- End of Function

-- Creation of Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger1 AFTER update of empname
    ON emp_table1 EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_ex();


-- insertion enteries.
INSERT INTO emp_table1 (empid, empname, salary) values (124, ' Sapmle_CustormerName', '3000');
```

Comment: Consider updating to a newer version of Postgres. 8.2 reached its `end of line` on December 2011.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To trigger `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception use:

```
Select empname INTO STRICT var_name from emp_table1 WHERE empid = 161232;
```

Details here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html

> If STRICT is not specified in the INTO clause, then target will be set
> to the first row returned by the query, or to nulls if the query
> returned no rows.
>
> If the STRICT option is specified, the query must return exactly one
> row or a run-time error will be reported, either NO_DATA_FOUND (no
> rows) or TOO_MANY_ROWS (more than one row).